# Paid G-Suite Scripted MailApp.sendEmail() function not allowing emails

Tags: email, google-workspace, quotas

We just upgraded our free Google Drive account to a G-Suite account as we are a retiree's social club of ~260 people and could not sent out our meeting notice emails as the Google Script MailApp.sendEmail() function limited us to 100 per day.  So we upgraded to a paid G-Suite account (allegedly a 500 mail/day limit) and after days of work to transfer Sheets and Scripts to the new account find the we ARE STILL LIMITED TO 100 mails a day, when our understanding was we could send out our 260 mails if we upgraded.

This is now a nightmare for us. How do we go about getting this fixed?  I tried a Tech Support phone call but after sitting in the waiting queue for almost 45 minutes today, I finally hung up.  PLEASE HELP.

Comment: I am surprised no one has answered this question.  There are hundreds of answers in various blogs and forums, but all are contradictory and none (I can find) have answered this. I am not a happy camper to have paid to get results and are getting NONE!  Someone please jump in here.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since this post is over 6 months old, you most likely resolved your issue, but I figured I'd go through what I've learned so far so this might help others.

As far as I can tell, the Google Scripts MailApp API limit increases to 1500 when upgrading to G Suite, but as you've learned, it's not immediate. I've been working with two G Suite accounts. My first account has been G Suite Basic for quite awhile now and other was a legacy account for quite some time. You can confirm your current limit using the following code, which I believe I found in the API Reference docs:

```
var emailQuotaRemaining = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
Logger.log("Remaining email quota: " + emailQuotaRemaining);
```

This applies to both the MailApp and GmailApp APIs, even though `getRemainingDailyQuota()` is only available under MailApp. I forget why exactly, but I believe I could only use aliases as a 'from' address using the GmailApp API, but mainly I use the MailApp API.

So now I'm migrating my scripts over to the account that was recently upgraded. But we're currently on a 30 day trial period, which means you're still technically limited to 100 email recipients via the APIs. Here are the two articles that provide some details regarding quotas and limits: 
https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852 & https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

The first article indicates that you can increase your limits by ending your trial. This can be done by making a manual payment and waiting about 48 hours. Which is good news if I need to exceed 100 recipients per day. However the second article says

> Note: Newly created G Suite domains are subject to the consumer limit for the first billing cycle if they have six or more users, or several billing cycles if they have fewer users. For more information, see the Help Center page on sending limits.

But I've had a legacy account for many years, so I don't know if it's considered a "newly created G Suite domain", and whether or not I'll still be under the " consumer limit for the first billing cycle..." -OR- "...for several billing cycles..." Which is concerning to me because I only have 4 accounts under that domain. Contacting G Suite support chat yielded no clear answers on the subject. They just keep telling me that they aren't trained to support Google Scripts and that I should look for answers on community sites like this one.

Hopefully this is helpful to some people, but unfortunately it is still unclear as to when quotas and limits increase exactly.

EDIT:

I finally spoke with someone at Google support that could explain, in better detail, that note in the second article. Basically, you must pre-pay at least $30 (regardless of the # of accounts) to end the consumer limits. Perhaps that was immediately clear to some, but their wording was confusing to me. They say six or more users for the first billing cycle because that would hit the $30 threshold necessary to increase your limits.

This link may also be helpful: https://script.google.com/a/directss.net/dashboard